# POI 3.7 - writing 50K+ rows using SS usermodel

Tags: apache-poi

I am trying to create a sheet with 50K+ rows using POI 3.7 but the generation is maxing out at 32768 rows. I understanding that createRow() function, which takes a variable of type int as input has a limit of 2 raised to power of 32 - 1 and that may be the limitation here.

Has anyone else faced this issue and if so, is there a workaround that can be used to generate a sheet with possibly 60K or 80K rows. Please let me know, if you have any feedback/ideas on how to generate 50K+ rows using SS usermodel.

Comment: Swap to the XLSX format which allows for more rows than XLS did?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am generating xlsx format file itself. I am using SS usermodel as it helps with both xls and xlsx format files.

Comment: Firstly, upgrade to something modern and supported, [POI 3.7 was released more than a decade ago!](https://poi.apache.org/devel/history/changes-3x.html#3.7). Then, create a `XSSFWorkbook` not a `HSSFWorkbook` to get the XLSX format and allow more rows

Comment: Latest POI version (5.1.0) allows HSSFWorkbook to have max of 64000 rows - this is basically an excel limit - not a POI limit. XSSFWorkbook allows about 1 million rows.

Comment: I doubt that the problem results from a row count limit. Probably you do something wrong while creating cell styles and reach the limit of unique cell formats/cell styles. But without seeing code ... -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.